# Method Naming Convention Question (most languages)

Tags: methods, naming-conventions, naming

If I have a method that hides a button, I would probably call it *HideButton*
If I have a method that shows a button, I would probably call it *ShowButton*

But what do you guys call a *ShowIfThisHideIfThat* style method?

Possible Choices:
*TestForButtonVisibility* (this kind of sounds like it will return true/false but not actually do the work)
*TestButton*
*ShowHideButton* (style I'm currently using)

Been at this a number of years and still don't have a style that I like for these types of methods. I'm working mostly in C# and a little Java, Ruby, and F#. What do you use for method names in this regard?

```
// example of the style of method
public void ShouldIShowOrHideButton()
{
  Button.Visible = ((chkSomeSetting.Checked) && (DateTime.Now.Day < 8));
}
```

Comment: Button::SetVisible (...)

Comment: Not that I like this style either... but another choice might be ShouldIShowOrHideButton()

Comment: One problem with this approach that may be the cause of confusion is that you have business / domain logic intermixed within UI logic.  What is chkSomeSetting representing and why must day be less than 8.  If this was wrapped up inside a nicely named function it would explain what the check meant and return a bool.  That function could then be incorporated into the UI either directly or via a view model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about `updateButtonVisibilty()`?

Answer (score 4):

Might be overengineering, but the reason you may have problems because it's doing two things.  So making sure you only have a function doing a single thing, howabout a method to determine if the button should be shown or not (takes parameters, returns bool), then set the value of the button directly.

```
  Button.Visibilty = DetermineIfButtonShouldBeShow(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this point. Depending on the previous code written in a project - sometimes I use this style. I really do like the use of the word Determine +1

Answer (score 3):

My preference has been to keep toggle methods rather than separate methods for hide/show.

```
ToggleButtonVisibility()
```

This allows you to put your testing code in there and the expected result/output would be a properly visible/invisible button.

Edit: Toggle is a personal preference that stems from a partial background in working with binary gates, architecture, etc where a toggle may go through several separate gates before reaching an end state. The word itself could be changed to anything else such as Update, Determine, Finalize, or even Steve. It really boils down to what makes sense to you and what your standard is.

Comment: But toggle just reverses the setting? It doesn't have any logic in it does it? Like only enable the button if a checkbox is checked and it's the first week of the month.

Comment: ToggleButtonVisibility() suggests that it toggles the button visibility, not that it shows or hides depending on state.

Comment: @Tyndall: I was thinking it was a good name, but I see your point

Comment: @tyndall - toggle could reverse the setting, but toggles are not necessarily binary conditions. If other conditions are not met, it could be that the toggle has no effect, but the end result is that the button is properly visible/invisible. I've even gone so far as to have a singular toggle method for multiple buttons/controls because the logic/settings/etc were intertwined enough that it helped cut down on unnecessary code.

Comment: Regardless, "toggle" implies the state *will* change. In this case, the state *might* change.

Comment: @Joel Etherton - I like that design. I usually have one method to call to update all the visible/enabled settings on a form. That makes thing much simpler, especially since there are usually several controls to update for any particular setting. If the state changes (or might possibly have changed), then just call that one method and forget about it.

Comment: @Andy Thomas-Cramer - I get what you're saying. His question asked us for what we use. I answered with what I use. Feel free to disagree with my naming convention. I will feel free to continue using it :)

Comment: My lack of toggle knowledge is showing. I have always used it as a reverse current state in my programming. I have no background in gates or electronics.

Comment: @Jeffrey, I often work towards that as the end goal. That style works well in greenfield projects or when you get to completely rework a form.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: Now your question is edited to include the example

```
// example of the style of method
public void ShouldIShowOrHideButton()
{
  Button.Visible = ((chkSomeSetting.Checked) && (DateTime.Now.Day < 8));
}
```

My answer is **neither**. I would do two things:

1. Move the `Button.Visible` part outside the function, so the function just computes the logic and returns `bool`.
2. Name the function according to its **internal logic** not according to whether it is for a button or not. So if your function checks for a wedding day it would be called `IsWeddingDay`, if it checks for a monthly meeting it would be `IsMonthlyMeeting`.

The code would be

```
Button.Visible = IsMonthlyMeeting()
```

and the logic can be subsequently used to control any other widgets if needed.

**Old Answer**: 
You probably need to explain more what *ShowIfThisHideIfThat* does.

If it depends on one condition, like:

```
if (condition)
    ShowBotton()
else
    HideButton()
```

then I would use

```
Button.SetVisibility(condition)
```

as per Lazarenko's comment above, or if the language has properties:

```
Button.Visible = condition
```

If you have two conditions like what *ShowIfThisHideIfThat* seems to imply, equivalent to:

```
if (cond1)
    ShowButton()
else if (cond2)
    HideButton()
else
    LeaveButtonAsItIs()
```

then the logic in my opinion is complicated and I wouldn't use one function. Sure, the code is equivalent to

```
Button.Visible = cond1 || (!cond2 && Button.Visible)
```

but you lose the understandability.

Answer (score 1):

I would use one of these:

- setXVisibility
- refreshX or refreshXStatus

Answer (score 0):

How about using  `SetButtonVisibility( )`

Answer (score 0):

The confusion seems to stem from a mixing of the business logic and the UI logic.  The test isn't whether the button should be shown.  Code is going to use the test to decide if the button should be shown.  It probably depends on whether some feature should be available.  Consider:

```
if (IsFeatureEnabled()) {
  ShowButton();
} else {
  HideButton();
}
```

This is the code where business logic (`IsFeatureEnabled()`) meets UI (`ShowButton()`/`HideButton()`).